# Understanding errors

Tags: solidity, remix, bsc

So, I'm setting upon percentage shaving on a token, but I keep throwing an error. Anyone can point to some resource to understand what the heck I am doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Please post your code. The error is clear. Int to address, Type error

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
address payable target = payable(0x1a...27) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read [the documentation here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#address)

This part specifically:

> Implicit conversions from address payable to address are allowed, whereas conversions from address to address payable must be explicit via payable(<address>).

So you have to convert it explicitly using address payable target = payable(...);